# Lodash reject get return object

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
var obj = {a: [], b: [1,2], c: [], d: [1]};
```

How do I get a non-empty array of objects like the following:

```
{b: [1,2], d: [1]}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do and what have you tried so far. Show your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you are after, using [`pickBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#pickBy).

```
var result = _.pickBy(obj, function(val){
    return val.length > 0;
});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/W4QfJ/3160/

*Note:* Unlike `filter()` and `reject()`, this returns an object, keeping your original structure (rather than an array).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this: `_.omitBy(obj, _.isEmpty);`

Answer (score 0):

[_.filter()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#filter) is what you're looking for:

```
var obj = {a: [], b: [1,2], c: [], d: [1]};

console.log(_.filter(obj, function(o){ return o.length; }))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [_.reject()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#reject) like in your title, you can do something like this:

```
_.reject({a: [], b: [1,2], c: [], d: [1]},function(o){ 
   return o.length == 0 
});
```

Comment: What's the difference between _.reject and _.filter?

Comment: reject is just the opposite of filter. So for reject you return true if you want to omit that element. By contrast with filter, you return true if you want to keep that object.

Comment: _.reject returns an array

Comment: but I need an object

Comment: If you want an object, check out Matt's answer and `pickBy()`

Answer (score 0):

Right now, `Lodash` has a method called [_.omit](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit) that does exactly what you need:

```
> const object = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
undefined
> _.omit(object, ['a', 'c'])
{ b: 2, d: 4 }
```